# .htaccess with silex : not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, silex

I would like my app to be accessed with this url :
http://myserv.local/~user/web/

The site is a silex application.

Naturally the application works well with the url :

http://myserv.local/~user/web/index.php/

So I had done a .htaccess script to do my will :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    FallbackResource index.php

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The root http://myserv.local/~user/web/ works well with this .htaccess but my ajaxs, for example http://myserv.local/~user/web/databaseindex shows me a 404 error.

Please could you help me to make this work ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Thanks, but it stills doesn't work ..

Comment: you should add 
      DirectoryIndex index.php

Comment: Your RewriteBase is /web as your webpath is ~/user/web/index.php